# How to add the MVC Assemblies in the project.json File

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I couldn't find the project.json file in my project, I create new project and I select empty and then I try to enabling ASP.NET core MVC, but I stuck to find a project.json to add this

```
"dependencies": {
 "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "type": "platform"
 },
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
 "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"
},
```

How I get a project.json to add my code into project.json?
BTW I try to study from this tutorial

---

[image: [1]]

Comment: How did you create the new project? project.json is no longer supported, and has been replaced by the csproj file.

Comment: See this helpful explanation from MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/cli-msbuild-architecture. The project.json usage is stated to be deprecated, instead find out `csproj` file & configure it with MSBuild.

Comment: @natemcmaster i `create project > web > asp` core web applications. and that tutorial i to do a changes project.json,  you can see the pictures in my question

Comment: @natemcmaster im using visual studio 2017 that tutorial using visual studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 does not support project.json files. To install any package (including MVC) to an existing project, you can do one of the following:

1. Install via the NuGet Package Manager UI. In Solution Explorer, right click on "Project > References" and select "Manage NuGet Packages...". From there, you can browse to and install packages, such as the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui for more details. Repeat for all packages except Microsoft.NETCore.App.
2. Install via Package Manager Console. Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. Then type the command `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console for more details. Repeat for all packages except Microsoft.NETCore.App.
3. Finally, you can edit the csproj manually. In Solution Explorer, right click on your project name and go to "Edit (MyProject).csproj...". This will open a text editor where you can add the following code:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

All of these are equivalent.